# Get a specified array value from struct according to a function parameter value

Tags: c++

I have a struct that holds 3 different arrays like this for example

```cpp
struct MyArrys
{
int arr1[3];
int arr2[3];
int arr3[3];
}
```

I need to get a specified array according to a step value for example consider this function:

```cpp
int doSomething(int x,int y, MyArrs arrs, const int step, const int idx)
{
  int z = // get arr1, arr2, or arr3
  return x+y+z;
}
```

The step values are only 1,2 and 3 similar to the number of arrays.

I've tried to implement a function called `getArrayValue` which will return the corresponding array value according to the step

```cpp
int getArrayValue(const MyArrs& arrs, const int idx, const int step)
{
   switch(step)
   {
      case 0:
         return arrs.arr1[idx];
      case 1:
         return arrs.arr2[idx];
      case 2:
         return arrs.arr3[idx];
   }
} 

int doSomething(int x,int y, MyArrs arrs, const int step, const int idx)
{
  int z = getArrayValue(arrs,idx,step);
  return x+y+z;
}
```

This way works.

Is there a better way to do it? Could I use the SFINAE here? and how? Does it even worth using SFINAE?

Comment: it is unclear how you want to apply SFINAE here. I would have used a reference to the array, lets call it `arr_ref` and then access its elements like `arr_ref[0]` etc., but your function looks ok too. Whats wrong with the solution you have? Why do you think you need something better? What is "better" ?

Comment: I've updated the question. My solution works, but is there a way to get rid of the switch case ?

Comment: oh, I just noticed... in `do_something` the `step` is a function argument, then in `getArrayValue` it suddenly is a template argument. That wont work. Is it known at compile time or only at runtime?

Comment: My work owner hates to use switch cases for those situations I don't know why. So I'm searching for another way.
Actually, `step` should be known at runtime.

Comment: sorry, but you should do a minimum of reasearch before posting. Asking if there is something better than code that does not compile just shows that you didnt do any research, you didnt even try to compile your code.

Comment: for a runtime value a switch is as good as it gets. Your solution is no solution. "This way works" no it does not

Comment: I've tried this code on MSVC, this is a demo example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: no. Also msvc will not compile this code https://godbolt.org/z/s6qdoMTsz.

Comment: "My work owner hates to use switch cases for those situations I don't know why. " you need to ask them what they meant. Without explanation and in isolation the statement "I hate switch cases" makes no sense. For what a switch does there is nothing better than a switch, and this looks like a good case for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a table of pointer-to-member.

Example:

```
int getArrayValue(const MyArrays& arrs, const int idx, const int step)
{
    using AnArray = int (MyArrays::*)[3];
    static const AnArray arrays[] = {&MyArrays::arr1, &MyArrays::arr2, &MyArrays::arr3};
    return (arrs.*arrays[step])[idx];
}
```

Comment: it's exactly what I imagined, Thanks!